# Need to match any string between two delimiters

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match parts of a string. For example, in the following string

```
Fault,10.224.2.3:4450,XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0,AA,BBBBBB
```

I want to match the entire string and extract `Fault,10.224.2.3:4450` and `AA,BBBBBB`. However, I want to ignore `,XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0,`.

Note that the string to ignore includes the delimiters, the commas (`,`). The string to ignore may contain the following characters:

```
./_0-9A-Za-z
```

The position of the period (`.`) is not fixed. Other examples of the pattern I want to ignore are:

- `,XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0,`
- `,XX_XX0039_XXXXX/1,`
- `,X_XX0039_X/4,`

I am using the regex in Simple Event Coordinator.

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried? Also, what language are you writing the regular expression in?

Comment: It looks like everything is between commas - what separates what you want from what you don't want?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, every line contains, somewhere, two sets of double delimiters (",,"), and you want to remove `/,,.*?,,/` from the line?  What exactly do you mean by "ignore"?  Also, are you able to use PCRE, or are we coming up with solutions in BRE or ERE?

Comment: Applogies if I have confused , but wanted to match a string eg Fault,10.224.2.3:4450,XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0,AA,BBBBBB . But the problem is the XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0 is not constant and I can match on Fault,10.224.2.3:4450 and AA,BBBBBB so i need to ignore the string in between . I am writing the regex in Simple event coordinator .

Comment: Your logical requirements are Unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(\w+,\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+:\d+).*?,(\w+,\w+)

Comment: Applogies if I have confused , but wanted to match a string eg Fault,10.224.2.3:4450,XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0,AA,BBBBBB . But the problem is the XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0 is not constant and I can match on Fault,10.224.2.3:4450 and AA,BBBBBB so i need to ignore the string in between . I am writing the regex in Simple event coordinator .

Comment: Thanks a lot I got the string the regex is as follows : Fault,\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+,[\w-]+,.*?,AA,BBBBB

Answer (score 0):

The best is to avoid your delimiter `,`

Regex:

`[^,]+`

Result:

```
        [0] => XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0
        [1] =>  
        [2] => XX_XX0039_XXXXX/1
        [3] =>  
        [4] => X_XX0039_X/4
```

Comment: or `[^,\s]+` if string doesn't contain space character

Comment: Applogies if I have confused , but wanted to match a string eg Fault,10.224.2.3:4450,XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0,AA,BBBBBB . But the problem is the XX_XXX0039_XX.XX/0 is not constant and I can match on Fault,10.224.2.3:4450 and AA,BBBBBB so i need to ignore the string in between . I am writing the regex in Simple event coordinator .